# How to show products with category filter in header search Magento

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to display category based `auto suggest` results in header `search`,

**form.mini.phtml**

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">   
     <select id="select-category" title="Select your category" name="cat">
        <option value="0" selected>Select category</option>
        <?php
           foreach ($categoryCollection as $category) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></option>
         <?php } ?>
     </select>
     <div class="input-box">
        <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
        <input id="search" type="search" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text required-entry" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Search entire store here...') ?>" />
         <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button search-button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
    </div>    
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
         var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '');
         searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]>
   </script>
</form>
```

[image]

In this Form, When I type in input box ajax request passed like

```
http://127.0.0.1/site/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/?q=bla
```

but selected `cat` value not include in this url, How can I include `Cat="bla"` in `ajax/suggest` url like

`http://127.0.0.1/site/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/?q=bla&cat=bla`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented this search functionality on any category page, you can get category id to filter in your controller from :

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
```

If you wish to still edit the ajax call for pages other than category page, you can edit it in :

magento/js/varien/js.js (debug initAutocomplete function)